# Spivak's Calculus Chapter 11, Problem 39 (a)

Tags: calculus

Prove that if $f$ is a twice differentiable function with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ and $f'(0) = f'(1) = 0$, then $|f''(x)| \geq 4$ for some $x$ in $[0,1]$.

Hint: Prove that either $f''(x) > 4$ for some $x$ in $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, or else $f''(x) < -4$ for some $x$ in $[\frac{1}{2},1]$.

Can somebody please provide a proof? I have been struggling with it. As an example of the effort: I assumed that $f''(x) < 4$ for all $x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$. Then Mean Value Theorem gives us,

$\frac{f'(x) - f'(0)}{x-0} = f''(x') < 4$ for some $x' \in [0,x]$. So, $f'(x) <4x$. Similarly, $\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = f'(x') < 4x' < 4x$. So, $f(x) < 4x^2$. But then I could not progress any further.

Comment: What have you done in these "struggles"? You should demonstrate an effort to actually solve the problem before coming to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's note $a = \max f''$ and assume we can integrate $f''$. Integrating $| f'' | \le a$ twice over $[0,x]$, you get $f(x) \le \frac{x^2}{2}a$ (Z).

Consider $f(1/2)$ and suppose it's above $1/2$. Applying (Z) yields $1/2 \le f(1/2) \le a/8$, hence $a \ge 4$.

If $f(1/2) \le 1/2$ replace $f$ with $g(x) = 1-f(1-x)$.

--

Actually this first solution draft was not particularly good, the following is better.

We assume $f(1/2) \ge 1/2$ and we will prove that $\forall x \le \frac12, f''(x)<4$ leads to a contradiction.

(note: if $f(1/2) < 1/2$, as mentioned above, $g$ would satisfy the conditions of the problem and verify $g(1/2) \ge 1/2$ etc.).

Let $h(x)=f(x)-2x^2$ ; we have $h(0)=h'(0)=0$ and $x \le 1/2 \implies h''(x)=f''(x)-4 < 0$. So $h$ is strictly concave on $[0,1/2]$ with $h(0)=h'(0)=0$. It follows easily that $h$ is concave, not constant $0$, negative and decreasing on $[0,1/2]$. And this contradicts $h(1/2)=f(1/2)-1/2 \ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I haven't learned integration yet (the book I am following does not deal with integration yet), so I don't understand the proof.

Comment: Actually integrability of $f''$ is not required at all, you get $| f'(x) | \le a x$ from Darboux applied to $f''$, the assumption in the answer was just to make it quicker and give a general direction to the proof. In any case, you should find a way to get to equation (Z).